# JS and React Native: node.js doesn't accept 'import' keyword

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, webstorm

I'm a beginner in using JavaScript and the framework React Native.

I have the task to program a mobile web app with React Native with another student from my class. He started to build an app, which is build without any problems on his Android Emulator. He sent me his App and node.js (my editor is JetBrains WebStorm, my partner uses the same editor) does not recognize my import react.

But when I start the app in my command line with react-native run-android everything function and I can see the app, but **my problem is 
that I can't run it from my editor.**

I have already install those in my command line:

```
C:\Users\Hang>npm install -g yarn
C:\Users\Hang>npm install -g react-native-cli
```

What did I forget to install ?

Here is a screenshot of the message that I get when I try to run the App:

[image: screenshot from the errormessage]

Comment: what is your webStorm version? Do you have `node_modules/react` in your project, is this folder included? what do you mean saying that you can't start react-native from editor?

Comment: My version is 2017.1.3. Yes i do have node_modules/react in my project and the folder is included. Actually I meant by this, when I try to run my index.android.js file , I expect it to load the App in my Android Emulator, but it doesn't function. At my partner's computer it functions so I think there is missing an installation of something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **Node.js** Run configuration to start your application, but Node.js doesn't support ES6 modules natively (thus the `Syntax error`on `import`), and, of course, it doesn't support react-native cli options, so running `node index.android.js` as you do won't start your app in android emulator. You should have used **React Native** run configuration instead. Please see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/12/developing-mobile-apps-with-react-native-in-webstorm/, *Running and debugging the app* section

Comment: And, please, rename the question -it's misleading. it's not the editor that doesn't recognize imports - from your screenshot I can clearly see that imports are correctly recognized in editor. It's node.js that doesn't accept 'import' keyword because it doesn't support ES6 modules

Comment: thank you very much! you solved my problem! ok, i just renamed my question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the react Native CLI for your IDE (webstorm)

[you will find It here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/12/developing-mobile-apps-with-react-native-in-webstorm/)

Comment: thanks for your answer! Actually I thought that I already did it, could it be that I have to install it in another folder? because i install it here : C:\Users\Hang>npm install -g react-native-cli

Comment: Do you have node and npm installed on your pc?

Comment: So, do you have node and npm installed?

Comment: yes i did it already. Could there be something else be missing, I put a screenshot under this comment maybe you can understand better what's the fault

Comment: Have you installed all the dependencies (node_modules) ?

Comment: can you explain me that how to do it ? yesterday my friend put in the command line:  npm install